# The current path, account/login/, matched the last one

Tags: python-3.x, django

Мне надо по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/ отобразить форму авторизации, но не удаётся, 404.

```
Page not found (404)
“....../PycharmProjects/shoppinglist/account/login” не существует
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
Using the URLconf defined in ecosys.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
topics/ [name='topics']
topics/<int:topic_id>/ [name='topic']
categories/ [name='category']
categories/<int:category_id>/ [name='in_category']
^(?P<path>.*)$
```

Приложение account.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'realestate.apps.RealestateConfig',
```

вот что я добавил в urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("realestate.urls")),
    path('account/', include("account.urls")),

]
```

собственно делаю по аналогии с приложением realestate

account/urls.py

```
"""Определяет схемы URL для account."""

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    # Login page
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

далее account/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm

def user_login(request):
    """Форма авторизации"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

account/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

и все это должен отобразить login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Всем спасибо, что дочитали до конца. Надеюсь на помощь!

realestate/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


app_name = 'realestate'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('categories/', views.category, name='category'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Покажите realestate.urls

Comment: проверьте, где у вас шаблон `login.html` лежит, возможно путь к нему нужен `account/login.html`

Comment: К сожалению добавление account/login.html не помогло, но этот путь оставил, там действитель так должно быть.

Comment: Добавил в конец сообщения  realestate/urls.py

Comment: У вас в обоих urls импортирован `static`, но в обоих случаях он почему-то не используется. Мне кажется, вы от нас что-то скрываете...

Comment: Дериктории с шаблонами тоже соблюдены. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Дополнил сообщение

Comment: Отсюда возникает логичный вопрос: а если отключить DEBUG — может, форма отобразится?

Comment: изменил DEBUG = False, ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1'],  в терминале получаю "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145, а в браузере Server Error (500)

Comment: Как минимум это означает, что форма хотя бы попыталась отобразится. Короче, этот ваш `static` внутри realestate перехватывает абсолютно все адреса, в том числе `account/login/` перехватывает тоже, и соответственно вместо отображения формы получается отдача статического файла из MEDIA_ROOT, а так как файла `account/login/` там не существует, то и получается ошибка 404. Ну а почему без `static` получается ошибка 500, это уж читайте в консоли